# How to prevent a font from loading twice in my wordpress site?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, fonts

Am using ranking champ theme, and am using roboto as my font.

And also using Visual Composer, which has a subset of fonts and which is default to 'latin'

So I guess the main robot font and this 'vc' fonts are loading because I see two fonts in page source as

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='ranking-champtheme-custom-google-fonts-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%3A100%2C100i%2C200%2C200i%2C300%2C300i%2C400%2C400i%2C500%2C500i%2C600%2C600i%2C700%2C700i%2C900%2C900i%26subset%3Dlatin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

and

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='vc_google_fonts_roboto100100italic300300italicregularitalic500500italic700700italic900900italic-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%3A100%2C100italic%2C300%2C300italic%2Cregular%2Citalic%2C500%2C500italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C900%2C900italic&#038;ver=4.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I just dont want the second font laoded with `id="vc_google_fonts_roboto100100italic300300italicregularitalic500500italic700700italic900900italic-css"`

I tried using jQuery to set its `href` to none, but didnt work, intrestingly while inspecting I see the href removed as per jquery written but while searching in page source it is loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery("#vc_google_fonts_roboto100100italic300300italicregularitalic500500italic700700italic900900italic-css").removeAttr("href");
});
```

Anyone can tell me any way to remove the second font loaded.

Am not sure its because of Visual composer, as I see the `id` as `vc_google_fonts_..` am assuming VC is loading the font again.

Comment: I think you can exclude Google fonts from Visual Composer in the Visual Composer plugin settings

Comment: @Vald I didn't find any option to do so. If it is there can you tell where the setting is?

Answer (score 1):

I never used Visual Composer, but I have found [this](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/VC/pages/12615683/How+to+Manage+List+of+Google+Fonts) how-to page, which says the following:

> Visual Composer uses specific array of Google Fonts available to
>   Custom Heading element and element extensions for styling of heading
>   part. It is possible to change the list of Google Fonts by applying
>   filter vc_google_fonts_get_fonts_filter - it will return array of
>   Google Fonts list which can then be modified/rewritten.

So the solution might be to use that filter to remove the font in question.

```
function vc_remove_roboto_font( $fonts ) {
    ...CODE TO FIND AND REMOVE ROBOTO from $fonts list...
    return $fonts;
}
add_filters('vc_google_fonts_get_fonts_filter','vc_remove_roboto_font');
```

I'm not sure what elements the `$fonts` list contain, so the code above is not complete, but it can help you get closer to the solution.

Here is also a [GitHub example](https://gist.github.com/andrastudio/cc2d7a3c8ca0cd405c89691fd04eeb11) on how to add a font, which you might find useful.